# problem building a docker container based on debian:buster

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I'm trying to build a docker container based on debian:buster.
In the process I get the message:

```
Need to get 1211 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3257 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5 [225 kB]
...
 Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openldap/libldap-common_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
```

There is a package

```
http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openldap/openldap_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u6.dsc
```

available in the source package list. How can I persuade docker/apt-get/whatever to use it?

My dockerfile works fine with `debian:stretch`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you don't have Internet connectivity at least to *security.debian.org* over HTTP (port 80), as I can see your DNS is resolving to the correct IP (151.101.194.132).
What I recommend is to test in your command line with a curl as bellow:

```
curl -vvv http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openldap/openldap_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u6.dsc
```

MT

Comment: I tried the suggested curl command and it works nicely. No complaints about anything. Besides: all the other 600 packages can be retrieved. It is only the package from security.debian.org that does not work